# Screensharing over WebRTC and browser support

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, screensharing

I am trying to build screensharing over the browser. I am trying to find the best native implementation and did some initial online research

1. [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility) - available in FF. In chrome its a little weird
2. [WebRTC Tab Content Capture](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/webrtc-tab-content-capture) - I see its in proposal stage
3. [Screensharing a browser tab in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/) - A blog explaining other methods

Researching above everything seems to be around 2012 time frame and I want to know what is the latest?

**Question: Which current technologies/javascript API can i use and what is its support across browsers**

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: I am just reusing the code there. I think including them will just make the question absurdly long and not clear to those who read

Comment: What is issue? Not certain what Question is?

Comment: "Which technologies/javascript API can i use and whats it support across browsers"

Comment: Edited question to be more clear

Comment: Have you tried capturing `document` onto `<canvas>` element?

Comment: Do you propose to use HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream() ? Like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas. It seems not widely supported

Answer (score 1):

Screensharing is alive and kicking in Firefox, but atm requires the user modifying `about:config`. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857134/webrtc-websocket-screen-recording/36484696#36484696) for how. I believe they're working on removing that obstacle.

Chrome is similar but [not quite the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286010/getusermedia-not-capturing-the-screen-correctly), and AFAIK requires the user to install an extension.

I don't believe other browsers support this natively yet.

Comment: and you can have an extension to modify about:config for you! See [here](https://github.com/otalk/getScreenMedia/tree/master/firefox-extension-sample)

Answer (score 0):

You can save `html` document onto `<canvas>` or `<foreignObject>` of `<svg>` element, then send `data URL`, `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob` of `<canvas>` or `<svg>`; or alternatively, send `html` document as encoded string.

Comment: how will this help?

Comment: @footy  _"how will this help?"_ Not certain what you mean?  _"Question: Which current technologies/javascript API can i use and what is its support across browsers"_ `canvas.toDataURL()` and, or sending `<svg>` as `Blob`, `data URL` or `ArrayBuffer` using `FileReader` should be currently supported in most modern browsers

Comment: @footy For example, you can use [`canvas2html.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js) to draw the current `document` onto `<canvas>` element, send `Blob`, `ArrayBuffer` or `data URI` of `canvas` using `webRTC`

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Will give it a shot